# spring boot integration test with eclipse junit runner

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, junit

I am facing a problem of running my (Spring) Integration Test in eclipse.

I have a test class like that :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ImportCSVBatchIT {

    @Test
    public void myIT() {
       assertEquals(...);
    }

}
```

When I do a `mvn clean install`, everything works well, my test is run (I added the maven-failsafe-plugin), and if I add an instruction like `assertTrue(false)` and I re-play a `clean install` my build fails -> it's ok I added a wrong assertion.

If I do the same thing in eclipse with **right click -> Run as -> JUnit** (without doing a `clean install` after adding the wrong assertion), the test doesn't fail because it runs the version of the **last** *clean install* (when the wrong assertion was not here). So if I add new instructions and try to run it in eclipse I will not have **the last version of my test class** until I run a `mvn clean install`.

I would like to have the same behavior of my unit tests :

- I modify the class then I can run the test quickly in eclipse by doing *right click -> Run as -> Junit* (it works well for my unit tests, but not for my integration tests with spring)

Comment: do you have other tests besides this one? just may be DirtiesContext annotation might help